# Where can I find the descriptions of spells referenced in Faiths & Avatars?

Tags: spells, cleric, adnd-2e, forgotten-realms

I have AD&D 2e *Faiths and Avatars* supplement for Forgotten Realms. It contains descriptions and abilities for Specialty Priests - priests with additional capabilities (and restrictions) for each particular deity. Many have additional spells, or spell-like abilities that reference spells. However, some of these spells are in neither in the Faiths & Avatars book nor in the Player's Handbook. Can anyone point out or tell me where I can find an explanation of these spells?

For example, Tyr has Specialty Priests called of Holy Justices who can:

- At 3rd level cast *Strength of One* (as the 3rd level priest spell) 1 time/day.
- At 5th level cast *Memory Read*(as the 3rd level priest spell) 1 time/3 days.

This is just a sample of references to spells I have never heard of and can find neither in the Faiths & Avatars guide (as it has some new spells) nor in the Player's Handbook. What manual are they described in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two major sources of new spells for AD&D 2nd edition campaigns that predate *Faiths & Avatars*: the [*Tome of Magic*](http://www.dndclassics.com/product/17391/Tome-of-Magic-2e) and [*Forgotten Realms Adventures*](http://www.dndclassics.com/product/16797/Forgotten-Realms-Adventures-2e). Both of your example spells come from the ToM, for example.

A comprehensive reference for priest spells is the three-volume *Preist's Spell Compendium*, which, together with the four-volume *Wizard's Spell Compendium*, reputedly contain every spell ever published for AD&D 2nd edition. They were published late in the 2e era, so the set is a good reference for spells, even including their original sources. (Unfortunately, unlike the ToM and FRA, neither are available for sale in PDF at this point; though they likely will be made available in the future, as the similar *Encyclopedia Magica* has been.)

Answer (score 5):

Both those spells can be found in the [Tome of Magic](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/46525/tome-magic).